# flexbox mixin not existing in a sass/compass installation via SCOUT

Tags: sass, flexbox, compass-sass, scout-sass

Maybe anybody has a hint for me and helps me saving time going through a jungle. I installed the sass/compass GUI "scout" (on mac) and now I want to use the compass mixin for my flexboxes.

I can @import "compass/css3"; but the needed mixins are not available: e.g.: @include display-flex; does not work then. when I look into this folder :

```
Resources/vendor/gems/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/css3
```

I don't see a flex-box file there. searching the folder's files for "display-flex" does not lead to a result.

Answer (score 0):

Compass version 0.12 only has mixins for the original flexbox specification.  You need to upgrade to Compass 1.0.

Comment: perfect, i did not upgrade but switched to koala, which has the latest compass built in. thx